# How to compress a pdf with images

Tags: pdf, compression, size, reduce

I'm trying to compress a 30 Mb pdf file which contains scanned text book
i want to reduce the size to something less than 10 MB.
i tried many software like ghost script , Scribus , gimp , Inkscape and more
but no hope
any idea get appreciated .

Comment: Thank you for reply friend ,  the problem is  i tried to convert the book to png , jpg ,...every possible format the book size still bigger than what i want , the book contains 620 pages black and white hand written text , i tried OCR but no hope because as i mentioned its hand written .... so is there any chance to make it less than 10 MB ? i don't care about the format . any help would be appreciatd.

Comment: Thank you sir : i want the book for my tablet 10" reading  not for printing and yes it is monochrome , so is it possible to reduce the size and how ?

Comment: Thank you sir gs -sDEVICE=pdfimage8 -r16 is exactly what i need -@KJ